# Gson Retornar Array de Uma posicao

Tags: javascript, spring, gson

Olá

Tenho o método :

```
@RequestMapping("/olaMundo")
    public String iniciando(Model model, Cadastro cadastro){
        CadastroDAO dao = new CadastroDAO();
        dao.adiciona(cadastro);
        model.addAttribute("nome",cadastro.getNome());
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        String retorno = gson.toJson("{'nome' :'"+ cadastro.getNome()+"'}");
        return retorno;
    }
```

Gostaria que o gson retornasse tipo

```
 "{'nome' : 'Maria'}"
```

no meu javascrip retornar o nome

```
...
$.ajax({
                        type:  'post',
                        url:   'olaMundo',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {
                            nome     : nome,
                            endereco : endereco,
                            telefone : telefone,
                            email    : email
                        },
                        success: function(data){
                           alert(data.nome);
                        }
                    });
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não tem necessidade de usar o Gson para isso. Você pode fazer:

```
 return "\"{'nome' :'"+ cadastro.getNome()+"'}\"";
```

Usando scapes para a string ir com as aspas.

Comment: estou tentando e ainda não retornou nada,

Comment: Os dados salvam, mas não retorna alguma coisa

Comment: Veja no console do browser qual o status da requisição, talvez tenha algum erro lá..

Comment: Não apareceu erro. Tipo no json eu usava `JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(); json.put("retorno", "0");

                                        jsonArray.put(json);
                                        out.print(json.toString());` mas no gson eu nao sei

Comment: Deu certo, era o meu javascript que return false estava no lugar errado